# How can I read my epub books on the kobo app on my computer?

Tags: epub, kobo, ebook-management

I have an e-reader (Kobo Touch) where I have downloaded my ebooks in epub format. How can I read those books on the Kobo desktop app?

Comment: I think it would help to provide more information. Do your book have DRM or not? May-be you have both kinds? Also do you actually want to use the Kobo desktop app, or do you simply want to read your epub books on your computer? Finally, it may (or may not) be useful to know what kind of computer you have (Widows, Linux, Mac, other?).

Answer (score 1):

Attributed to [ebookfriendly.com](http://ebookfriendly.com/kobo-tips-tricks/):

> Authorize your device with Adobe DRM

Kobo is using Adobe DRM to prevent ebook files from unauthorized distribution. You should be aware of it before you start buying books on Kobo.

If you don’t authorize the device with your AdobeID, you will be only able to read the book on a first device to which you download it. It won’t open on any other device.

The key to flexibility is to authorize any app and device with the same Adobe ID.

If you accept the limitations Adobe DRM puts on a user, follow these steps:

1. Get Adobe ID. It’s a combination of the email address and a password you’ll use after signing up on Adobe site.
2. Authorize with your new credentials any of the devices/apps you use. Do it before you download the first ebook. Here is a [tip on how to authorize a computer and your mobile devices with Adobe ID credentials](http://ebookfriendly.com/2012/02/16/how-to-authorize-the-device-with-adobe-id/?preview=true).

> Back up Kobo books to a computer

The books you bought are stored on a device you use to read them. They can also be synced between devices.

How to get all of them to a computer? You can use Adobe Digital Editions application for that. There are versions for PC and Mac computers.

Again, make sure to authorize the computer with the same AdobeID, otherwise you won’t be able to open the books.

1. In Adobe Digital Editions, look for the command saying “Authorize” (Help menu). Type in your AdobeID.
2. Go to Kobo store, sign in and go to My Library. You’ll see here a list of all the books or book samples you downloaded from Kobo.

To download the book, click on the turquoise button on the right. ”Adobe DRM Epub” means the book has DRM and you’ll be able to open it only with ADE. “Download Epub” means the book is unprotected, so any epub reading application will open it.

The blog goes on with a number of collected links to other resources, including other blogs and videos, for specific importing steps for a number of readers. See those links at the bottom of the page at [ebookfriendly.com](http://ebookfriendly.com/kobo-tips-tricks/).

Comment: Not all books from Kobo are under DRM it is up to the poublisher. If non DRM then Adobe is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Open the desktop app (This is in version 4.6)

1. Goto My Books.
2. Then choose the book